# How can I push a repository to my computer and my online server?

Tags: wordpress, git, macos, github, repository

I have figured out how to create a repository on github. Now I am trying to push the repository to both my macbook pro and my server, which is hosted through http://namecheap.com, and be able to understand how to keep things simple. I am using wordpress on my server and I have a template theme. I want to edit my files on my mac and then push them to the website, keeping everything easy.

Answer (score 2):

There is plenty of [information](https://guides.github.com) out there on how to get started with github, so I will just focus on clearing up a misconception:

> Now I am trying to push the repository to both my macbook pro and my server

You do not `push` from github to a server. You need to `clone` your github repo to your development (macbook) and production (server) environments.

```
git clone https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```

https://help.github.com/articles/fetching-a-remote/

Alternatively, you can push existing code to an empty repository by initializing locally, setting your remote and then pushing

```
git init
git add -A
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
git push origin master
```

Once you have your repo setup, your typical workflow will look something like this:

- Make changes in your development environment (macbook).
- `push` those changes to github.
- `pull` those changes from github in your production or staging environment (server).

Answer (score 0):

One of the main things you need to use git this way is access to a terminal on the hosting serve, to push your files directly through git that should be installed as well.

Alternatively you can upload file using any available protocol such as (s)FTP or SSH direct to your server. In this case you'll be using git to version and manager your templates but not to upload or release them.

I've seen that cheapnames.com provides Softaculous as a mechanism to manage their servers. This software also provides synch and install scripts.